# Jquery validate plugin for file extension

Tags: jquery

I would like help with the jquery validate plugin. I used it to check the extension of the loaded file. When the extension is bad, it prompts to change the file, and when it is the right format it takes it into account.
The plugin works well in my code. The problem is that when I click on the submit button to continue when it is the right file, the button does not work, I can not go to the next page. Yet there are links between my pages. Can you help me please ?

Comment: why can't you use like this ex: <input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" /> . instead of validator for simple task. this will not allow user to upload file than you specify

Comment: Hi John. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html   dir="ltr"
    lang="fr-FR"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta   http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
    content="IE=10"/>
<meta   http-equiv="Content-type"
    content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta   http-equiv="Expires"
    content="0"/>
<title th:text="${@environment.getProperty('spring.application.title') + ' - ' + serviceTitle} + ' - Livrer le DDX'"></title>
<link id="favicon"
    type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
    rel="shortcut icon"
    href="images/favicon.ico"/>
<meta   name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link   rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
<link   id="mainCSS"    type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"    href="css/mainBS.css"/>
<link   id="workflowStageCSS"   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"    href="css/workflow-stage.css"/>
<link   id="uploadDDXCSS"   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"    href="css/uploadDDX.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>                  <div class="articleBody">
                        <form  id="ddxForm" name="ddxForm"  method="POST"   enctype="multipart/form-data"   th:action="${@environment.getProperty('server.context-path') + 'uploadDDX'}" >
                            <p class="ddx-block"> 
                                <label  id="ddx-file-label"
                                for="ddx-file"  class="ddx-file-label"
                                >Fichier matlab(*):</label> <input id="ddx-file"
                                type="file"
                                name="ddx-file" 
                                class="ddx-file" th:required="true"/>                                   
                            </p><div><hr />                         
                                 <input id="ddx-next" name="ddx-next"
                                    type="submit" value="Continuer &gt;&gt;"/> <hr /></div>
                            </form></div>       
                        </article>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
    <script>
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug:true,
  success:"valid"
});
        $("#ddxForm").validate({
            rules:{
                "ddx-file":{
                    required:true,
                    extension:"m"
                }
            }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for the **debug** option: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#debug

> Enables debug mode. If true, the form is not submitted and certain
>   errors are displayed on the console (will check if a window.console
>   property exists). Try to enable when a form is just submitted instead
>   of validation stopping the submit.

Try removing 'debug: true' from the setDefaults method after testing failure cases.

Comment: Thanks Chris C for your advice. I just had to remove 'debug: true' from the setDefaults method.